# How to create that background on my page with css

Tags: html, css

Please help me. I want to create shape like on image, on my page, this should be a background of section.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: tried `background:url(image.png);`?

Comment: can you post your code and explain on what element do you want your background?

Comment: Welcome to stack ovrflow :-) Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
I flagged this question for closing.

Comment: here is all page https://github.com/BeerDRinker/OnlineClinic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.yourtag {

 background: radial-gradient(circle at 91% 50%, transparent 35%, red 15px);

}
```

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p0ctco0m/1/

Comment: #bullet {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 91% 50%, transparent 35%, #fa6900 15px);
}

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add background image in `body` tag

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GpQI.png') no-repeat center center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  </body>
```